# Is there an advantage to building a road to a city-state before they request one?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

Occasionally city-states will request that you build a road to connect them to your trade network, giving influence when you do.  Is there any advantage to building a road to a city-state before they request it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  You can't form trade routes with city states, (at least with vanilla/G&K), so there isn't much a of a point to paying the cost of a road for nothing.  Unless you want to set up a route for invasion... ;)

See Affine's comment if you're wondering about BNW

Comment: Even in BNW, there's no point. Caravans don't need roads in order to setup trade routes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I haven't played BNW, and was going off something posted on a wiki.

Comment: Well, there is *one* reason I can think of; as soon as the city-state requests a road, you'll have one (almost) instantly, though its not really a good reason...

Comment: You'd be paying upkeep on a road that isn't doing anything for you, so this really isn't recommended unless you have a weird, specific reason for wanting a road.

Comment: @Affine - Don't roads allow your caravans to travel further, possibly opening up that city state for trade if it was too far without the road?

Comment: @DavidHarkness The question was specific to G&K and prior, which is the reason for the lack of any talk of BNW

Comment: @JeffLangemeier - Which is why I addressed my comment to Affine who mentioned BNW. It's good to have as much information, even something beyond but related to the original question.

Comment: Yeah, roads do extend your Caravan range, but you don't need it running all the way to the target. Still not a particularly good reason to build a road to a city-state - I've never seen a city state give more than 10g, and that's how much it will cost you in upkeep on that road.

Answer (score -5):

If you are friends/ally of that particular city-state, then, from my experience, you get some bonuses related to that city-state's type. Example - Building a road to a cultural city-state will grant more culture per turn.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @rsegal Presumably because this is not the least bit true, the amount of culture you get per turn only increases when you advance to another technological era, a road to the city state definitely does not increase the bonuses received from that city state in vanilla or G&K.

Comment: Oh, okay. That's a good reason.